# AWS Lambda function is returning square bracket "[ ]" result

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I created a Lambda function with an API query string parameter. My Lambda function is created in NodeJS with MySQL query as shown below resulted to square bracket "[]"when invoked in the URL and Postman but the status is "Succeeded".

URL Return/Result:

```
[]
```

Here's my Lambda function code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var config = require('./config.json');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : config.dbhost,
    user     : config.dbuser,
    password : config.dbpassword,
    database : config.dbname
  });

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      // Use the connection
      connection.query('SELECT DISTINCT meta FROM item WHERE meta LIKE "+event.selected-meta"', function (error, results, fields) {
      // And done with the connection.
      connection.release();
      // Handle error after the release.
      if (error) callback(error) ;
      else callback(null, results);
    });
  });
};
```

I suspect the culprit in my code is the callback method but it seems to me it is correct and could not find any other syntax to correct it.

Does anybody here familiar with AWS Lambda, NodeJS and API Gateway who could help me figure out where I was wrong?

**UPDATE 1:**

The above code returns "Succeeded" status but an empty array. I tried the same query in Workbench — I get the right results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM item WHERE meta LIKE 'tango';
```

I can now confirmed that the below parameter is taken up as a variable rather than as parameter. So, I have to determine the right syntax for parameter in Lambda/NodeJS.

```
"+event.selected-meta"
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

At last I got the answer! The right syntax would be as follows. The question mark (?) is the placeholder followed by an array as the second argument where we place the parameter and it solves my problem!

```
SELECT name FROM item WHERE meta LIKE ?', event['selected-meta']
```

Hope others can learn from this!

Comment: if I insert async within handler — exports.handler = async (event, context, callback), it would return a "null" result. I am still lost here...

Comment: The query doesn't have `%` so it may be related to that. what happens if you replace it with the following ? `'SELECT DISTINCT meta FROM item WHERE meta LIKE ?', '%' + event.selected-meta + '%'`

Comment: @Ersoy I tried your suggestion but it returns an error. The present code I have actually returned "succeeded" though the result is square bracket  "[ ]". I tried the query syntax in Workbench and it works. I feel, just like you, the culprit this time is +event.selected-meta. I think we should focus more on this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got the answer! The right syntax would be as follows. The question mark (?) is the placeholder followed by an array as the second argument where we place the parameter and it solves my problem!

```
SELECT name FROM item WHERE meta LIKE ?', event['selected-meta']
```

I am posting it here for others reference but I could not mark it as "ANSWERED". Somebody may want to check and mark it. Cheers!